# Graceful kill off a detached node.js spawned child process in Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, command-line-interface, kill

Not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706055/why-can-i-not-kill-my-child-process-in-nodejs-on-windows): I can kill process fine, I want to know how to detect, within the process, that it's being killed, and gracefully shutdown.

## **Overview:**

I have a CLI tool to spawn and kill a child node.js process. The demo code is contained in these three files:

`spawn.js` -- Will spawn the `child.js` script, detached. For simplicity, I pipe the child's `stdio` to an `out.log` file

`child.js` -- A simple counter which writes to a file, **uses the `readline` method to detect an emulated SIGINT in Windows**

`kill.js` -- Invokes a `process.kill()` on the child process, using it's PID

---

## **Code:**

**spawn.js**

```
'use strict';

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var childFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'child.js');

var out = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a');
var err = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a');

var options = {
  detached: true,
  stdio: ['ignore', out, err],
};

var child = spawn(process.execPath, [childFilePath], options);
child.unref();
```

**child.js**

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

if (process.platform === 'win32') {
  console.log('win32 true');
  var rl = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });

  rl.on('SIGINT', function() {
    process.emit('SIGINT');
  });
}

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  console.log('SIGINT');
  process.exit();
});

var filepath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'pid.txt');

fs.writeFile(filepath, process.pid);

var i = 0;
setInterval(function () {
  console.log(i++);
}, 1000);
```

**kill.js**

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');


var pidPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'pid.txt');


fs.readFile(pidPath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  process.kill(data, 'SIGINT');
});
```

---

## **Problem:**

When sending the `process.kill(PID, 'SIGINT')`, it doesn't actually detect it as a `SIGINT` in windows. I can run `child.js` manually and use `CTRL+C` to kill the process to trigger a `SIGINT`, so I know that the `readline` code is working (or maybe not since `SIGINT` will trigger without the `readline` code, but it will nonetheless trigger a `SIGINT`)

Does `process.kill()` not send the type of signal to a detached process? How do I detect that that a separate script is trying to kill my child process and shutdown gracefully?

Comment: try this: `spawn("taskkill", ["/pid", child.pid, '/f', '/t']);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I not kill my child process in nodejs on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706055/why-can-i-not-kill-my-child-process-in-nodejs-on-windows)

Comment: @Louy not duplicate because in that issue, reference to child is returned, but this is killing the child process from a completely difference node process. In addition, I'm already using `spawn`, as suggested in the accepted answer.

Comment: Windows doesn't have signals.  Node.js might emulate cross-process signaling, but it would be unusual for it to do so.

Comment: To clarify that last comment, it seems likely that process.kill on Windows ignores the signal type, and just terminates the target process.

Comment: @PGT I don't think it makes any difference whether that is a child process or not. Try using `taskkill` instead of `process.kill` as you'll get more predictable results. `/f` stands for `force` btw.

Comment: @Louy: tried `taskkill` and same result, didn't print the `SIGINT`.

Comment: I think you should listen using `process.on('exit')` instead in this case.

Comment: @Louy: tested and that doesn't work either. I think the process just gets kill in Windows and might not actually be a graceful way to exit without opening up some sort of communication channel like a REST API or with IPC.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem. I noticed the `rl.on("SIGINT")` is not working but `rl.on("close")` works!

```
var rl = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
})

rl.on('close', function() {
    process.emit('SIGINT')
})
```

Here is my debug output

```
Sat Feb 17 2018 11:43:28 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time) process started (pid=6920)
Sat Feb 17 2018 11:43:28 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time) SIGINT captured! cleanup and then call process.exit(0)
Sat Feb 17 2018 11:43:28 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time) byebye! (code=0, signal=undefined)
```

Note that I'm not pretty sure that adding extra code to a subprocess is a good idea. Think about forking a non nodejs process, it might not be able to use such trick (e.g. redis-server, kdb+). I am still looking for a way to let `spawn.js` to kill subprocess gracefully.

Update 1: Here is my initial problem reported to PM2 community
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3467

Answer (score 0):

There is a library [kill-with-style](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kill-with-style?activeTab=readme) to do this and works with detached process too. It has  various options to set signal, timeout and retry options.