# Node.js: how to check if spawned process was successfully killed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to stop a spawned process in Node.js. My `DownloaderWrapper` class, can spawn and make use of a few different downloader applications, which can be swapped out by changing the environment variable `DOWNLOADER_PATH`. However, I have noticed that depending on the downloader application being used it will not respond to the `SIGKILL` signal sent by the `stop` function and keeps running.

Is there any way I can ensure the stopping of the spawned process? Or if I cannot, can I detect if a process failed to stop and return `'failed'` in my `stop` function?

Testing on Windows.

```js
export default class DownloaderWrapper {
    constructor() {
        this.process;
    }

    async download(spawnArgs) {
        if (!process) {
            this.process = spawn(process.env.DOWNLOADER_PATH, spawnArgs, { windowsHide: true });
        }
    }

    async stop() {
        if (this.process) {
            this.process.kill('SIGKILL');
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                this.process.on('close', (code, signal) => {
                    console.log(`child process terminated due to receipt of signal "${signal}"`);
                    resolve('stopped');
                });
            });
        } else {
            return 'stopped';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're saying is happening shouldn't be possible according to the signal(7) man pages: "The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored." However, I'm not sure I'm understanding. Are you spawning a process which is then spawning another process which is some downloading program?

Comment: My script can spawn a downloader process. It is possible for the downloader process to spawn another process but I am sure I am issuing the `SIGKILL` signal before that happens. The downloader process is only ever spawned from my script.

Comment: Wait, it seems that you are returning the new Promise which contains the listener to resolve if the process was killed, but you have already killed the process prior to returning it, so it will never catch the 'close' event.

Comment: Using taskkill to kill the process on Windows worked successfully for all spawned processes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706055/why-can-i-not-kill-my-child-process-in-nodejs-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your stop function to this:

```
function stop() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       if (this.process) {
           this.process.on('exit', (code) => {
               resolve('stopped with code ' + code);
           });
           this.process.kill('SIGKILL');
       } else {
           reject('no process running');
       }
    });
}

// eg
stop().then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

I could be wrong, but I don't think there is any need to define your stop function as async since you are returning a Promise anyway. And in your original code you are killing the process before your listener is added. In addition, I can find no documentation in the official NodeJS documentation about a listener for Process.on called "close" which is why I replaced it in the code with process.on('exit'). Hopefully some of these things explain why you are not seeing any evidence that your process is being killed, because it isn't being killed, and even if it was, you wouldn't see a message because there is no such event as close.

In addition, with the way this code is, after the process is killed, you still have a Process object stored in this.process. If you were to call the stop() function again, then if(this.process) would still be true and it will try to kill it again. You might want to set this.process to null or undefined after you kill it, depending on your use case.