# processp spawn is not killed when the electronjs app is terminated

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

process spawn is not killed when the electronjs app is terminated.

Is there a way to access all child processes opened by electron js?

Thanks for listening

```
const proc = require( "child_process" ).spawn( "C:\\my-electron-app\\dist\\mysite\\mysite.exe runserver localhost:8000 --noreload", {shell: true} );

app.on(
    "window-all-closed",
    function()
    {
        process.kill(proc.pid)
        app.quit();
    }
);
```

Includes an image. In console.log I showed the PID of the spawn child process return. And it is not shown in the list of windows processes.

[image]

Comment: Try this module: https://github.com/pkrumins/node-tree-kill

Comment: Hi. I couldn't answer in advance, sorry. Did not work. I noticed that the return pid does not correspond to the active process in windows. Something you can do?

Comment: I don't know why would it have a different pid. Make sure you're looking at the right thing. Sort processes by pid and try to find the running process manually

Comment: Includes an image. In console.log I showed the PID of the spawn child process return. And it is not shown in the list of windows processes.

Comment: I'm not sure why, try the solutions described in other threads on stackoverflow, like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706055/why-can-i-not-kill-my-child-process-in-nodejs-on-windows